# Executing stored procedure in sql-server from vb6?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, vb6

Iam running a legacy VB6 application. I'm trying to execute a stored procedure that would go through a bunch of tables in SQL-SERVER, grab Data and put it into a table in SQL - SERVER. Do I need to declare and set a new recordset?

```
 dim strSQL as string
 strSQL = "Exec FillEmptyTable @blah = "& blah
```

It would seem that I don't need a recordset, but this doesn't execute

Now when i SET a new recordset, then it works

```
dim rs as adodb.recordset
set rs = new adodb.recordset
dim strSQL as string
strSQL = "Exec FillEmptyTable @blah = "&blah
rs.open strSQL, Connection
```

Is this right? I don't know why I need a recordset if I'm only creating one on SQL-SERVER side?

Comment: You really need to parameterize this instead of executing a string. There are hundreds of examples for doing this in VB6.

Comment: As you can see from your example, the line `rs.open strSQL, Connection` is the one executing the query on the [sql-server]. Withtout that line (in your first example) you are merely constructing the string to be executed but the string is not actually being sent to the server. The recordset is necessary, because [vb6] wouldn't actually know if data will be returned. But you might as well use it to check if the query executed as expected. Let the stored procedure return an `ok` if everything worked or an error code if something went wrong.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need a recordset because the SP returns no rows or you don't care about any rows it does return you can simply pass the SQL string to the connection object:

```
Connection.Execute strSQL, 0, adCmdText
```

See [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15222/How-to-Use-Stored-Procedures-in-VB) for a more formal way using a `Command` object that removes potential the SQL injection vulnerabilities implicit in manually building SQL in a string.